# Gitlab-ci - Pipeline status is 'succeeded' in overview

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is as follows:

```yaml
always_on:
    before_script:
        - echo 'before_script'
    script: echo 'script done'

always_fail:
    before_script:
        - echo 'before_script'
    script: fail_now

backend_only_mr:
    only:
        refs:
            - merge_requests
            - master
        changes:
            - scripts/**/*
    before_script:
        - echo 'before_script'
    script: echo 'script done'
```

As you can see, there is `always_fail` job which always fails. If I have no changes in `scripts` directory, this works fine and Merge-request overview shows the pipeline is failed:

[image: Overview - Normal case]

When I have made a change in the `scripts` directory, the job fails, as expected, but the overview shows that the job has succeeded because `backend_only_mr` is succeeded:

[image: Overview - Change in scripts]

The jobs are as follows:

[image: Job - Merge request]
[image: Job - Always running]

`backend_only_mr` is flagged as `detached`, if it helps.

Comment: could you paste the entire gitlab ci file? or the screenshot of the entire MR or Master pipeline? I want to see if the always fail step executes on mr or master pipelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior currently, as the two pipelines run for the commit and merge request separately.  Then the merge request pipeline passes "after" the commit one fails, and GitLab sees it as passed.

There are a couple of options to deal with this:

1. Specify `only: merge_requests` on every job you want to count against "can we merge this"?
2. The new global [`workflow` setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrules) lets you say "I want all of my jobs to run on a merge request pipeline".
3. There are a number of issues around how consolidated pipelines should work going foward.  Would love your feedback in thos.

You also can read more about how we're solving for this with `rules:` vs. `only/except:` here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#key-details-when-using-rules.